# How to handle matrices of different dimensions using templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I would like to achieve the conversion of a matrix to a string, regardless of its size(s), type or dimension(s). Using templates, I've managed to make it work by defining one template for each "sort" of matrix I need.

Template for arrays:

```
template < typename NUM, std::size_t SIZE >
std::string to_string( const std::array< NUM, SIZE > &arr ) {

    std::string buf;
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
        buf += std::to_string( arr[i] ) + " ";

    return buf;
}
```

Template for 2-dimensionnal matrices:

```
template < typename NUM, std::size_t INNER_SIZE, std::size_t OUTER_SIZE >
std::string to_string( const std::array< std::array<NUM, INNER_SIZE>, OUTER_SIZE > &arr ) {

    std::string buf;

    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < OUTER_SIZE; i++ ) {
        for ( uint32_t j = 0; j < INNER_SIZE; j++ )
            buf += std::to_string( arr[i][j] ) + " ";
    }

    return buf;
}
```

However, I'd like to make the solution more 'elegant', by only having a generic template that could handle matrices regardless of their dimensions. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Why not use a dynamic size vector or something?

Comment: counterpoint: Does your matrix really need to be templated on its dimensions? I implemented a matrix class a while back and started with it being templated thusly, but quickly found it was far easier to stop doing that and have the dimensions be regular members, with a `vector` as backing and logic to index (and validate attempts to do so). That is *more* generic than using templates, since templates only aid genericity for certain definitions of _"generic"_, and otherwise they can hinder it.

Comment: I agree with other comments, but for now, you can start noticing that the inner loop in the second snippet can be replaced by a call to `to_string(arr[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: I strongly suggest to avoid to give your functions the same name of a standard function. So, in the following example, I've renamed `fooString()` your function to avoid the risk of a clash with `std::to_string`.

Second: as observed by Bob__, if you replace the inner loop with a call to `to_string(arr[i])` (`fooString(arr[i])`, with my renaming), you resolve recursively the problem of the multidimensional (for every dimension) array.

Third: I suggest to write a ground case that get the `std::to_string()` for a single value (where `T` is the base (not array) type, like `int`, `float`, etc.)

```
template <typename T>
std::string fooString (T const & val)
 { return std::to_string(val); }
```

and the recursive case become

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
std::string fooString (std::array<T, Dim> const & arr)
 {
    std::string buf;

    for ( auto const & elem : arr )
        buf += fooString( elem ) + " ";

    return buf;
}
```

With a ground case that treat a base type you have one more level of indirection (so performances are, presumably, a little worse) but the logic of array management is only in one function and not almost equal in two (less error prone maintaining the code).

The following is a full working C++11 example

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::string fooString (T const & val)
 { return std::to_string(val); }

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
std::string fooString (std::array<T, Dim> const & arr)
 {
    std::string buf;

    for ( auto const & elem : arr )
        buf += fooString( elem ) + " ";

    return buf;
}

int main()
 {
   std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 2U>, 3U>, 4U> a3dim
    {{ {{ {{  2,  3 }}, {{  5,  7 }}, {{ 11, 13 }} }},
       {{ {{ 17, 19 }}, {{ 23, 29 }}, {{ 31, 37 }} }},
       {{ {{ 41, 43 }}, {{ 47, 53 }}, {{ 59, 61 }} }},
       {{ {{ 67, 71 }}, {{ 73, 79 }}, {{ 83, 89 }} }} }};

   std::cout << fooString(a3dim) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work like a charm and is way simpler than what I was expecting! Side note: those templates are indeed encapsulated in a _namespace_ to prevent any clash with the standard function.